# File not found exception while adding images

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, filenotfoundexception

need a lil help here

m trying to insert images (in EmployeeTable) of employees

```
    Protected Sub ImageAddButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ImageAddButton.Click
 Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString").ToString)
    con.Open()
    If EmployeeIDTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter EmployeeID to Add Photo")
    Else
        Dim com As New SqlCommand("UPDATE EmployeeTable SET IMAGE = (@IM) where EmployeeID='" & EmployeeIDTextBox.Text & "'", con)
        **Dim imageData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(FileUpload1.FileName)**
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IM", imageData)
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

getting an error at the line in **... help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to look like this:

```
Protected Sub ImageAddButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles     ImageAddButton.Click

Dim imageData as Byte() = New Byte(FileUpload1.FileContent.Length){}
FileUpload1.FileContent.Read(imageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FileUpload1.FileContent.Length))

 Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString").ToString)
con.Open()
If EmployeeIDTextBox.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Enter EmployeeID to Add Photo")

Else
    Dim com As New SqlCommand("UPDATE EmployeeTable SET IMAGE = (@IM) where EmployeeID='" & EmployeeIDTextBox.Text & "'", con)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IM", imageData)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: @AdityaNawandar, sorry about the typo: Just updated the answer. Use `imageData` instead.